# Guest PC and Host connected as if on lan

Tags: windows-7, networking, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am trying to connect the guest win7 in the VM to the Host win7 so they act as if on lan, i would be able to access the localhost in the host and also connect to the internet.

In the settings of the virtual machine, i see these adapters, But I initially selected Shared Networking (NAT)

[image]

I opend command prompt in both guest and the host and types `ipconfig/all`, these are the results

Guest

[image: guest OS]

Host
[image: host OS]

I pinged both host and guest IPv4Address, but it timed out
I pinged google.com on the guest OS, again it timed out.

what Am i missing?

Comment: So you're on WiFi, is that correct? Unfortunately WiFi client adapters cannot be bridged.

Comment: The host is using a wireless adapter to access the internet. does this means the guest and host cannot see each other (lan)?

Comment: It means the bridged guest won’t be able to access the network. That means no Internet and no internal communication. // Whether there is a possible solution depends on your specific needs. Do you need to access the VM on the same adapter that accesses the Internet? Because otherwise an *additional* “Local only” adapter might do the trick.

Comment: i just need the guest OS to be able to access the internet, access localhost in the host, perhaps through IP, and the host be able to access localhost on the guest